# Performance, sql heavy join vs multiple small request

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following Mysql database structure

```
[Table - Category1]

  [Table Category1 -> Category2 ] (One to N relation)  

[Table - Category2]

  [Table Category2 -> Item ] (One to N relation) 

[Table - Item]
```

and I want to get everything into an array in PHP with the following structure

```
$arr[$i]['name'] = 'name of something in category1';
$arr[$i]['data'][$j]['name'] = 'name of something in category2';
$arr[$i]['data'][$j]['data'][$k]['name'] = 'name of something in item';
```

So basically I don't know if I should use one "heavy" sql request with JOIN like the following one or use an iterative method

The join request

```
SELECT c1.name as c1name, c2.name as c2name, i.name 
FROM category1 c1 
LEFT JOIN category1_to_category2 c1tc2 ON c1.id = c1tc2.id_category1 
LEFT JOIN category2 c2 ON c1tc2.id_category2 = c2.id
LEFT JOIN category2_to_item c2ti ON c2.id = c2ti.id_category2
LEFT JOIN item i ON c2ti.id_item  = i.id
```

The iterative method

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM category1';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
while ($arr[$i] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $join = $mysqli->query('SELECT c2.id, c2.name FROM category2 c2 LEFT JOIN category1_to_category2 c1tc2 ON c2.id = c1tc2.id_category 2 WHERE c1tc2.id_category1 = '.$arr[$i]['id']);
    $j = 0;
    while ($arr[$i]['data'][$j] = $join->fetch_assoc())
      /* same request as above but with items */
    $i++;
}
```

The iterative solution will make around 10 * 20 request which seems a lot to me that's why I would choose the first solution (4 JOIN single request).
However, with the single request solution, my array will look like that

```
$arr[0]['c1name'];
$arr[0]['c2name'];
$arr[0]['iname'];
```

And it will require some PHP traitement to obtain the desired array which I require to display in tabs in an HTML page. So my question is, is it better to have one big SQL request with some PHP array manipulation or to have multiple small request without the PHP array manipulation ? I know that in most case, getting all the data from SQL is a better solution but in this case I'm not sure. By the way, my only consideration is the loading time of my web page.

Thanks in advance for your help =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typically better, and your example is no exception, to have the SQL server do as much of the data formatting and iteration as possible as SQL servers are typically more efficient at the task than common programming languages.

Add to this that you are cutting down on query load of the server and you have a very good reason for using complex joins.

The only downside is complex SQL queries can be hard to format and debug, if not already using a 3rd party SQL tool I would recommend getting one.

Answer (score 0):

To go with the answer by Wobbles (that I agree with), I would suggest that you do a single query but you store the last key for each of c1name, c2name and iname. When these change you increment the relevant array subscript and initialise the lower level ones again to build up your array.

Something like this:-

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT c1.name AS c1name, c2.name AS c2name, i.name  AS iname
        FROM category1 c1 
        LEFT JOIN category1_to_category2 c1tc2 ON c1.id = c1tc2.id_category1 
        LEFT JOIN category2 c2 ON c1tc2.id_category2 = c2.id
        LEFT JOIN category2_to_item c2ti ON c2.id = c2ti.id_category2
        LEFT JOIN item i ON c2ti.id_item  = i.id"

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$k = 0;
$c1name = '';
$c2name = '';
$iname = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    switch(true)
    {
        case $row['c1name'] != $c1name :
            $i++;
            $j = 0;
            $k = 0;
            $arr[$i]['name'] = $row['c1name'];
            $arr[$i]['data'][$j]['name'] = $row['c2name'];
            $arr[$i]['data'][$j]['data'][$k]['name'] = $row['iname'];
            break;
        case $row['c2name'] != $c2name :
            $j++;
            $k = 0;
            $arr[$i]['data'][$j]['name'] = $row['c2name'];
            $arr[$i]['data'][$j]['data'][$k]['name'] = $row['iname'];
            break;
        default :
            $k++;
            $arr[$i]['data'][$j]['data'][$k]['name'] = $row['iname'];
            break;
    }
    $c1name = $row['c1name'];
    $c2name = $row['c2name'];
    $iname = $row['iname'];
}
```

As an aside there is some code at work that is used to generate a menu. Just 2 levels, and it was originally coded as one query for the first level and then one query for each of the records in the first level to get all the items below it. Not complex (there are only ~16 items in the first level, and on average under 10 items below each of those). I rewrote that to a single joined query. Typical time to generate that menu dropped from 0.25 seconds down to 0.004 seconds. It is easy for the time taken sending queries to the database to rapidly become excessive.